# Do all modern Kernels use 3 kinds of scheduler?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, scheduling

I'm referring to the **Long-term**, **Mid-term**, and **Short-term** scheduler.

Do these three always work in conjunction during scheduling or can they be implemented separately?  One without the other two or two without the other one?

This really confuses me.

Answer (score 2):

Do remember that the number and type of scheduler a system has, completely depends upon the configurational requirements and what it takes to create a stable system.

A **long term scheduler** manages the degree of multi-programming of a system. Its primary responsibility is to make sure that programs are loaded into main memory from the storage location i.e it changes the state of a process from **New** to **Ready**.

A **short term scheduler** allocates processor to the programs lying in the main memory. It also controls the degree of context-switching. Thus it changes the status of the process from **Ready** to **Running** and vice versa or from **Running** to **Waiting**.

A **medium term scheduler** controls *swapping* i.e. moves programs in-and-out of the main memory.

> In modern time-sharing Operating Systems like Windows, **long term
>   scheduler** is absent and the programs are directly sent to main
>   memory in the **Ready** state.

Therefore, the answer to your question is, No, all modern Kernels do not use all the 3 kinds of scheduler.